# Error building shopizer

Tags: shopizer

I want to customize shopizer ecommerce  . After downloading the source code version 2.0.2 from github I imported the project into eclipse luna using the import option of "Existing Maven Project".

Followed  there getting started documentation but getting the following build errors : -

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 4 projects -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.shopizer:sm-core:2.0.2-SNAPSHOT (E:\shopizer-   2.0.2\shopizer\sm-core\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find com.shopizer:shopizer:pom:2.0.2-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of org.springframework.maven.snapshot has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 11 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]    
[ERROR]   The project com.shopizer:sm-core-model:2.0.2-SNAPSHOT (E:\shopizer-2.0.2\shopizer\sm-core-model\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find com.shopizer:shopizer:pom:2.0.2-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of org.springframework.maven.snapshot has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 7, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.shopizer:sm-core-modules:2.0.2-SNAPSHOT (E:\shopizer-2.0.2\shopizer\sm-core-modules\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find com.shopizer:shopizer:pom:2.0.2-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of org.springframework.maven.snapshot has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 11 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.salesmanager:sm-shop:2.0.2-SNAPSHOT (E:\shopizer-2.0.2\shopizer\sm-shop\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find com.shopizer:shopizer:pom:2.0.2-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of org.springframework.maven.snapshot has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]  
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

These are the steps I followed after importing the project into eclipse : -

1 )    Right click on shopizer which is the main parent project and run maven clean install , I am using the maven plugin for eclipse ie m2e .

2 )    The build error says that there is a non-resolvable parent pom , which I try to solve by providing a relative path element in the 4 sub-modules of this multi-module project , but does not help.

I can also seen some version differences , like the parent pom has

```
<groupId>com.shopizer</groupId>
<artifactId>shopizer</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

where the version is 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT but the parent element of the child modules have this entry

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.shopizer</groupId>
    <artifactId>shopizer</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

I did go through the only single question asked on this forum about shopizer build but the solution provided over there did not solve my problem .

I hope a solution to this problem can be of help to others who are trying to customize shopizer for the  own needs and also to others who are just starting out in Java Enterprise Application development .

Hoping for some help . Thank you for your co-operation .

Comment: Try with new `2.0.3`

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this problem earlier and after researching a bit I found out that shopizer-2.0.2 had some problems . Its better one tries with the earlier version ie shopizer-2.0.1 . Try and see if it solves the problem .